# How to pass a parameter to windows service from client machine

Tags: c#, windows-services, error-logging

I want to write error log from windows service. I know to call a customcommand from windows service, but it will not allow any parameters. I want to pass my error message to service and the customcommand will write the log. How can I do it. I tried something

> I have created a static string variable in my library class.
>   Whenever an error occurs I am calling the function like

```
ATELib.AteBAC.getErrorMessage = "error message from client";
ServiceController Controller = new ServiceController("ATELogsService");
if (Controller.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
{
    Controller.ExecuteCommand(128);
}
```

and the code in my service is

```
protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
{
    if (command == 128)
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + @"\ATELogCheck.txt", true))
        {
            file.WriteLine(ATELib.AteBAC.getErrorMessage);
            ATELib.AteBAC.getErrorMessage = null;
        }
    }
}
```

it is creating the errorlog file(ATELogCheck.txt) but the error message(string value) is not there in the file, creating an empty txt file. It is a static variable even why it is writterning empty. I am using tcp protocol and calling the service object as

```
baCls = (ATELib.AteBAC)Activator.GetObject(typeof(ATELib.AteBAC), "tcp://localhost:9090/ATE");
```

How can I pass the string value to the service?

Comment: Creating a static variable within a library doesn't automatically make that variable(and its value) available to the various processes that reference that library.  The `ATELib.AteBAC.getErrorMessage` variable between your service and the client are not the same. You need some form of IPC to send this string.

Comment: I'll complicate things for you a bit. We used an ETW listener on the windows service, the client can then generate ETW custom events and send them to the windows service. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751538(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Because your service runs in different domain from your application. So the `ATELib.AteBAC.getErrorMessage` in your application is different from `ATELib.AteBAC.getErrorMessage` in your service.

I honestly think, if you have to do something like this, you have issues in the design of your application. The service is really there to do something continuously. Or, it can "sleep" and listen to TCP port. Once signal received, it can find work and execute. Definitely, look into design first, before going into unneeded complexities.

Comment: Thats great for why it breaks, but not how to pass the value which is what the OP is asking.

Comment: Is there any way to pass message to windows service??

Comment: WCF using named pipes binding. Remoting. YOu need to communicate between two different live processes. And .Net has means of that. But to be honest, I don't see why you need this for logging. Application should be able to log things on its own. And in the worth case scenario, you could have a queue created by application and read by service.

Comment: service will keep listening the port and keeps the object alive in singleton pattren. I want to pass the error message. and I don't know about WCF

Comment: Service will listen to the port if you use sockets to listen to it. Service by definition is a long-running process. Independently, what object you use, singleton or not. Usually, people put timers and make service look for job once tick occurs. But I am saying that, for example in your case, you can use this `OnCustomCommand(int command)` to receive command "to do something". Your service needs to know how to find work and execute unit of work on separate thread. Otherwise it may collect too much work. Your question wasn't "what is WCF". You got the answer why your stuff not working :o)